# How can I write this code snippet so that it echo's the response when submitting empty fields?

Tags: widgets

So I am developing a newsletter subscriber plugin and I am trying to create a mailer so I can send an email and get a request back and have my form update and give me a message. In the newsletter-subscriber-mailer.php file I am trying to check to see if a post has been sent, but the code I wrote seems to be absolutely useless. It is supposed to echo out a response if I try to subscribe without adding post data and it doesn't, instead it submits successfully absolutely nothing, empty fields. All I want to do is make sure that the name and email are filled out.

```
<?php
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
                // Get Post Data
                $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
                $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
                $recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];

                // Validation
                if(empty($name) || empty($email)){
                        // Send Error
                        http_response_code(400);
                        echo 'Please Fill Out All Fields';
                        exit;
                }
        }
```

I know I can add required to the Name and Email fields in the newsletter-subscriber-class.php and I did have it, but I temporarily removed to ensure that the code snippet above is working.

```
<?php

class Newsletter_Subscriber_Widget extends WP_Widget {

        /**
         * Sets up the widgets name etc
         */
        public function __construct() {
                // widget actual processes
                parent::__construct(
                        'newsletter_subscriber_widget', // Base ID
                        __( 'Newsletter Subscriber', 'ns_domain' ), // Name
                        array( 'description' => __( 'A simple email subscriber', 'ds_domain' ), ) // Args
                );
        }

        /**
         * Outputs the content of the widget
         *
         * @param array $args
         * @param array $instance
         */
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
                // outputs the content of the widget
                echo $args['before_widget'];

                echo $args['before_title'];
                if(!empty($instance['title'])){
                        echo $instance['title'];
                }
                echo $args['after_title'];
                ?>
                        <div id="form-msg"></div>
                        <form id="subscriber-form" method="post" action="<?php echo plugins_url(). '/newsletter-subscriber/includes/newsletter-subscriber-mailer.php'; ?>">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name: </label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" >
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email: </label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="email"  name="email" class="form-control" >
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="<?php echo $instance['recipient']; ?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php echo $instance['subject']; ?>">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="subscriber_submit" value="Subscribe">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) between setting the post variables and the validation to see what it thinks is in them.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $email );
print_r( $name );
echo '</pre>';
```